# Using Set<Integer> to remove indexes in an List<String>

Tags: java, integer, hashset

I have an ArrayList of strings TrackArray which define unique ids of tracks.
I also have a `Set<Integer> indexSet` to save the indexes of the tracks ids I need to remove from the TrackArray.

I tried the following:

```
public void deleteAllTracks(){
    if (!indexSet.isEmpty() ) {
        TrackArray.removeAll(indexSet);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    indexSet.clear();
}
```

The code is not working, probably because it doesn't cast the Integer into int in the RemoveAll. I haven't found another workaround except deleting one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal solution would be to change `indexSet` from `Set<Integer>` to a `Set<String>`. Otherwise you can't use it to remove elements from your `ArrayList<String>`.

If you can't change it, you can convert it to a `Set<String>` with:

```
Set<String> strIndexSet = indexSet.stream().map(Integer::toString).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

So you can write:

```
public void deleteAllTracks(){
    if (!indexSet.isEmpty() ) {
        TrackArray.removeAll(indexSet.stream().map(Integer::toString).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    indexSet.clear();
}
```

However, it would be less efficient to run this conversion every time your method is called.